# Track changes to all calls of updated method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-4.0

I have a method called `DoStuff(string LastName)` that's called many times in our application. Every call will send a *LastName* to `DoStuff(string)`.

The method has now been modified, and it will now receive a *FirstName* instead of a *LastName*, but the signature remains the same at `DoStuff(string);` which means no build errors.

Every method that calls `DoStuff(string LastName)` will not have to be modified so that a *FirstName* is sent. It's not just refactoring/renaming the method name or the argument.

For the sake of the example, let's say that this call is made 100 times. This means that I will to change the code so that a *Lastname* is sent. What tool, preferably within VS, can I use to make sure that all calls were correctly changed so that a *FirstName* is sent?

I guess what I'm looking for is the equivalent of what the IDE would do if I decided to change the method to `DoStuff(int)`.

Comment: I don't see any difference between `DoStuff(string LastName)` and `DoStuff(string LastName)`. Am I missing something? I really don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you saying that you now want all callers of the method to pass a different value than they were passing previously? Giving an argument a different name doesn't change anything - it's a non-breaking refactoring.

Comment: @itsme86: sorry about that. Changed the code.

Comment: All calls to `DoStuff(string Lastname)` will now have to be changed so that I send `DoStuff()` `FirstName` instead of `LastName`.

Comment: That's not a breaking change, that's just a refactoring of an argument name. You don't have to do anything

Comment: I would like to track which calls were updated so that `FirstName`  is sent.(instead of `LastName`)

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can select the method name and then choose "Find Usages", which will shows you the places that the method is called within the solution.